# Using jQuery to redirect a youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have jQuery on my site. I also have a youtube video using a standard object/embed code. How would I use jQuery so that when the youtube video finishes playing, the page is redirected to a new page?

** EDIT ***

This is my youtube embed:

```
<div id="embed_player">
    <object id="embed_object" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="385" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/LgJxPKfV8sw">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/LgJxPKfV8sw">
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="true">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=0&hd=1&fs=1&rel=0&version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer">
    </object>
</div>
```

I have tried adding the following javascript to my page, but with no success...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind to the onstatechange event:

onStateChange
This event is fired whenever the player's state changes. Possible values are unstarted (-1), ended (0), playing (1), paused (2), buffering (3), video cued (5). When the SWF is first loaded it will broadcast an unstarted (-1) event. When the video is cued and ready to play it will broadcast a video cued event (5).

Some good documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener

Comment: How would I bind to this event in jQuery? jQuery is not my forte.

Comment: Please read the documentation, it is very clear. Specifically under the section "Subscribing to Events" they give a good example of how to use onstatechange event and how to get the current state.

Comment: If you still have problems after reading documentation than post them here :)

Comment: You need to pass in the id as a param, add <param name="playerapiid" value="myytplayer"> and then change to document.getElementById('playerapiid')

Comment: Also you'll need to set another param: enablejsapi to 1. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters for full list of params

Comment: Okay, I have added the playerapiid parameter, but the events are still not firing.

Comment: you also need to add <param name="enablejsapi" value="1">

Comment: Yes, I have that... its in my original code in flashvars `  playerObj = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
  playerObj.addEventListener("onStateChange", test);` this code is giving me errors

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Ah, looks like you are binding the event before the player is ready. You need to define a function "onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId)" and add the event inside there.

Comment: Okay, I now have this:
`function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}`

But its still failing to fire off the alert; just no error now.

Comment: I did an alert test, and `onYouTubePlayerReady` is not firing.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're passing in enablejsapi in param flashvars, it should be passed in as it's own param (same with playerapiid)

Comment: I tried it both ways, doesn't make a diff. On the youtube api page though, it shows it as a flashvar, not it's own param.